# Better way of using AWS parameter store? 1. Keeping all variables in a single parameter as JSON 2. Keeping every variable as a separate parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, appsettings, ssm, aws-parameter-store

I have a web app to be hosted on AWS cloud. We are reading all application configuration from AWS parameter store. However, I am not sure if I should have all the variables as a single parameter in a json format or have one parameter for each variable in parameter store.

Problem with having a single parameter as json string is, AWS parameter store does not return a JSON object, but a string. So we have to bind string to a model which involves reflection (which is a very heavy operation). Having separate parameter for each variable means having additional lines of code in the program (which is not expensive).

Also, my app is a multi-tenant app, which has a tenant resolver in the middleware. So configuration variables will be present for every tenant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no right answer here - it depends.  What I can share is my team's logic.

**1) Applications are consistently built to read env variables to override default**
All configuration/secrets are designed this way in our applications.  The primary reason is we don't like secrets stored unencrypted on disk.  Yes, env variables can be read even so, but less risky than disk which might get backed up

**2) SSM Parameter Store can feed values into environment variables**
This includes Lambda, ECS Containers, etc.
This allows us to store encrypted (SSM Secure), transmit encrypted, and inject into applications.  It handles KMS decryption for you (assuming you setup permissions).

**3) Jenkins (our CI) can also inject env variables from Jenkins Credentials**

**4) There is nothing stopping you from building a library that supports both techniques**
Our code reads an env variable called secrets_json and if it exists and passes validation, it sets the key/values in them as env variables.
Note: This also handles the aspect you mentioned about JSON being a string.

**Conclusion**
The key here is I believe you want to have code that is flexible and handles several different situations.  Use it as a default in all your application designs.  We have historically used 1:1 mapping because initially SSM length was limited.  We may still use it because it is flexible and supports some of our special rotation policies that secrets manager doesn't yet support.

Hope our experience lets you choose the best way for you and your team.

Comment: The reasoning looks plausible. I have better judgement out of your experience now:-) Thanks much for sharing your views, @sfblackl